# How to increase the paging limit in magento 1.9 REST API

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, category-tree, page, rest-api

I am using the following code to fetch category tree where almost i want to fetch around 1000 records  but only getting  100 records because of limit.

$resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/categories/store/default?limit=100";

Here limit=100 is the maximum value if it exceed,  like

$resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/categories/store/default?limit=101";

it is giving the following error

[image]

Please help me to get through this problem and provide solution to increase this limit to 1000 or more vlaue.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the `\Mage_Api2_Model_Resource::_applyCollectionModifiers` method, you will see that the limit is hardcoded :

```
if ($pageSize != abs($pageSize) || $pageSize > self::PAGE_SIZE_MAX) {
        $this->_critical(self::RESOURCE_COLLECTION_PAGING_LIMIT_ERROR);
}
```

with `const PAGE_SIZE_MAX     = 100;`

So, unless you rewrite this class, you will not be able to bypass this limit.

I think you should use the param `page` to get all the 1000 products you want :

get the 100 first with 
`$resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/categories/store/default?limit=100&page=1";`

then  `$resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/categories/store/default?limit=100&page=2";`

to get the product between 100 and 200 of the collection, etc, etc until `page=10`.